# HttpResponseCache dose not work on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I am facing one issue with respect to the implementation on `HTTPResponseCache`. The implementation work very well in `Android 4.0.3` Version present in Galaxy S2 device, where as same code does not work for me in Galaxy S3 device with Android 4.0.4 version.

While reading the `InputStream` it throw the exception URL not found in Airplane mode.
If some body have an idea, please share on it.

Thanks.

Please find the peace code and exception occur while sending the request on Galaxy S3.

```
    private void executeGETRequest(){
        InputStream inStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try{
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/target");

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();       
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(true);
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Client-Identity", getHeader());
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale=" + NetworkConstants.MAX_STALE_TIME);       
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();//Point where the error occur

        if(null != inStream){
            result = convertStreamInToString(inStream);
            //result output
        }
        result = null;
        inStream.close();
        inStream = null;       
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printstack();
        }
    }
```

and the exception is

```
:- 10-22 14:10:35.110: W/System.err(6194): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.example.com": No address associated with hostname
10-22 14:10:35.110: W/System.err(6194):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:400)
10-22 14:10:35.110: W/System.err(6194):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
10-22 14:10:35.110: W/System.err(6194):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
10-22 14:10:35.110: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
10-22 14:10:35.110: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at com.network.NetworkManager.executeGETRequest(NetworkManager.java:257)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at com.network.NetworkManager.processRequest(NetworkManager.java:325)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at com.network.NetworkManager.access$0(NetworkManager.java:307)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at com.network.NetworkManager$1.run(NetworkManager.java:408)
10-22 14:10:35.115: W/System.err(6194):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not going to go very far with out the code you are using